# OpenSSL - RSA PSS - is there a way to use pre-defined salt values?

Tags: openssl, cryptography, bouncycastle, signing

Is there a way to use non-random but pre-defined salt values for RSASSA-PSS signature generation with OpenSSL? I know that this would not be the standard way to generate signatures using that scheme, however we want to develop some regression tests for our platform and need a fixed set of inputs / outputs for that. One way we've come up so far is to use a proprietary RNG for salt generation, which we can manipulate to give the numbers we would require. Is there a way to do this with the standard OpenSSL API?

Comment: What is SSA in *RSASSA-PSS*?

Comment: RSASSA-PSS combines the RSASP1 and RSAVP1 primitives with the EMSA-PSS encoding method as defined in RFC 3447.

Comment: I think `RAND_set_rand_method` will work, as long as you _aren't_ using an `ENGINE`, but have never done it myself. @oliv: and in particular SSA means Signature Scheme with Appendix, for both RSASSA-PSS and RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5; see section 8.

Comment: @oliv Or see [this question / answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/8820/1172) that explains the "with appendix" part.